# Cassandra: in a multi-DC cluster, does each DC have complete data set?

Tags: cassandra

I thought this is obvious: in a multi-DC cluster, so long a keyspace utilizes replication in each DC, the result is that every DC has a full set of data: the tokens, physical rows, etc.

However, when reading this doc [(Manual repair: Anti-entropy repair)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesManualRepair.html), I am confused by this statement:

> The nodetool repair tool does not support the use of -local with the -pr option **unless the datacenter's nodes have all the data for all ranges.**

The bold text (I added) seems to suggest that a datacenter may not contain "all the data for all ranges"

Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, the documentation is a bit misleading. Each data center will definitely contain copies of the entire set of data if it is being replicated to that data center. A clearer note would be

> The nodetool repair tool does not support the use of -local with the -pr 
>   option unless the datacenter's nodes have all **copies of the data** for all ranges.

Basically, the -pr option will try to repair all replicas for a particular range, across the entire cluster. But -local will restrict the repair to just the local datacenter, so they're conflicting options.

Comment: That makes a lot sense now. Thanks!